# How to query values when a column has N value

Tags: sql-server

So I have the following table:

[image: Table example]

And I'm trying to write a Query where I can send the code BR_BN as a variable in my WHERE clause
and if I get BR_BN then I want to retrieve the records with this code AND the records with the Code_FS RB02. On the other side when I get the value AB_CP, I want to include the recordes with the Code_FS RB01.

Here's the Query I've tried so far:

```sql
DECLARE @Code_OB VARCHAR(20) = 'BR_BN'
SELECT * FROM Dummy_AV
WHERE FK = 2
OR
(@Code_OB = 'BR_BN' AND Code_FS = 'RB02' AND Code_FS = @Code_OB)
```

But it doesn't work, it retrieves all the records regardless of the FK, and/or the @Code_FS.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `@Code_OB = 'BR_BN' AND Code_FS = 'RB02' AND Code_FS = @Code_OB` this can ***never*** be true. If the column `Code_FS` has the value `'RB02'`, it's *can't* also have the same value as `@Code_OB`, as the prior clause states it must be `'BR_BN'`. `'BR_BN'` <> `'RB02'`.

Comment: its confusing. what is the expected result ? and as larnu said, there is a critical semantic error in your query

Comment: It sounds like you maybe need another table to define these relationships, which could then be joined in to the query. But its not really clear what you are trying to do. If you add some inputs and expected results that would help. Also providing the sample data as text not an image helps enormously, as it lets us set up our own version of the data to play with much more quickly

Comment: `if I get BR_BN then I want to retrieve the records with this code AND the records with the Code_FS RB02` Why not the rows with Code_FS RB01 ? What is the logic behind this ? How can you know with value `BR_BN` that you need only value `RB02` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't note the FK = 2 being needed, yet you have it in front of an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause. I think this is what you're after, if it isn't exactly what you're aiming for hopefully it gets you on the right track. For future questions, always helpful to paste your sample data as data instead of an image.

```
DECLARE @Code_OB VARCHAR(20) = 'BR_BN'
SELECT * FROM Dummy_AV
WHERE FK = 2 -- you will get all rows where this is true
OR
((@Code_OB = Code_OB AND Code_FS = 'RB02') OR (Code_OB = 'AB_CP' AND Code_FS = 'RB01')) -- you will get all rows where one of these is true
```